# AEM: How to find location of Exception on Sightly/HTL page?

Tags: aem

I'm working on a fairly large HTL page, which is throwing a:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid property name`

How can I find the location in the HTL that's causing this?

UPDATE

The full trace is too big for SO. I saved it here: http://pastebin.com/xajiY5MD

Here's the first few lines:

```
Invalid property name

Cannot serve request to /content/XXXX/en-us/cart.html in /apps/XXXXcommerce/components/content/cart/cart.html

Exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid property name
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.utils.RenderUtils.getProperty(RenderUtils.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.utils.RenderUtils.resolveProperty(RenderUtils.java:143)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.apps.XXXXcommerce.components.content.cart.SightlyJava_cart.render(SightlyJava_cart.java:512)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.impl.engine.runtime.RenderUnit.render(RenderUnit.java:54)
```

Comment: Can you share the log trace. Or you can see it in error.log file under crx-QuickStart/logs folder. Log file have the page load request full trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid property name` without a property name apparently occurs when indexing an array using an empty value (in my case the object containing the index had gone out of scope)

Answer (score 0):

This comes when you are using a property which is:
1. not defined in dialog
2. You are using it in a wrong manner(Check for double quotes vs single quotes)
3. If you are using java, that property is not present in the java class and you are trying to access it.

Pls check and respond if thats no the case and the resolution too to help others.